# How to resolve the problem in builtins.pyi?

Tags: python, file, built-in

[See this file named builtins.pyi](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2and3/builtins.pyi)

When I opened it there was one problem reported in the file underlining the `int` with red mark:

```
class _SupportsIndex(Protocol):
    def __index__(self) -> int: ...
```

The `int` after this `->` is underlined. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Underlined in what? Sounds like whatever is doing your syntax check is older than python 3.5.

Comment: @jordanm Hey, so how to install syntax check for ```3.8.2```? I am working on ```VSCode```. Do I need to update ```VSCode```?

Comment: I don't use vscode, so I have no idea

Comment: have you tried to update the python plugin in vscode?